# How to accept input into array

Tags: java, arrays, input, block

I have a server and client. The client will send a message, which is encrypted, to the server and the server will decrypt it. If the message block size is more than one, it will only send the last letter to the server to decrypt. I am trying to use array but am not sure how the server will be able to get to decrypt the message as it will only get the last letter. Can someone please help?

Comment: Why is it only sending one character?

Comment: With most encryptions the server won't be able to decrypt it only with the last char, but why would it send only the last letter? Is there such a requirement?

Comment: as you can see from the comments and the answer, either your question or your requirements are **clearly nonsensical**.  Please restate your question.

Comment: I can't judge if it's nonsensical or not, but it's definitely from a newbie. It would help if you add the code your client use to request and the one your server use to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this:

> am not sure how the server will be able to get to decrypt the message as it will only get the last letter

The server can't decrypt your message because it doesn't have enough information. You can be sure of it.

Comment: +1 - It is **physically impossible** to decrypt information that you have not received.